# Bubble sort algorithm has a bug where some numbered lists don't sort correctly in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, sorting

I am new when it comes to algorithms and am starting from the bottom with the bubble sort. I created my implementation and it seems to work 9/10 times sorting a list of numbers from 1-100.

However there are rare times where it is not sorted properly and there will be 1 random number that doesn't get sorted fully.

Not sure where the error in my code is and have come to stack overflow for help.

algorithims.js

```js
const sortArr = [51, 54, 63, 98, 100, 86, 80, 52, 88, 6, 75, 22, 64, 66, 84, 91, 12, 73, 9, 90, 41, 85, 37, 2, 46, 57, 58, 1, 31, 87, 78, 93, 82, 55, 47, 20, 43, 21, 70, 50, 53, 15, 19, 39, 11, 30, 33, 83, 7, 77]


//This bubblesort algoritihm sorts a numbered list

let bubbleSort = (arr) => {
  let counter = 0

  for (let i = 0; i <= sortArr.length; i++) {
    if (sortArr[i] > sortArr[i + 1]) {
      counter += 1
      sortArr.splice(i, 0, sortArr[i + 1])
      sortArr.splice(i + 2, 1)
    }
  }

  if (counter > 1) {
    bubbleSort(sortArr)
  } else {
    console.log(sortArr)
  }

};

bubbleSort(sortArr);
```

Comment: Sorry, but that does not look like a standard bubble sort. Bubble sort has nested loops. This is probably why it is not "always" working.

Comment: @crashmstr I've never seen one before. I just read what the rules were and tried to create it off the top of my head

Comment: Why `counter > 1` ? why not `counter >= 1`? for a case like this `3,5,3,3,` it will be counter = 1 and one swap. Which means `3,3,5,3`? It should really fail more.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty i was just running a quick test without any duplicate numbers. Thanks for answering my question though. Works like a charm.

Comment: Using `splice` in a sort seems odd. That isn't the standard way to swap two elements.

Comment: @JohnColeman ya I've never used an algorithm like this before. I jsut read that a bubble sort was swapping two numbers and came up with my own solution. I understand its not the most optimal way. I was just trying to figure it out before looking at the optimal solutions

Comment: The problem with `Array.splice()` is that it doesn't just affect the two items being swapped. Swapping two elements should be `O(1)` rather than `O(n)`

Comment: @JohnColeman appreciate the response John. I will read up on big O notation.

Comment: @crashmstr it's a recursive variant of bubble sort

Comment: @MitchelPaulin Yes, I saw that later, so there is a lot more wrong than I thought at first. Especially as it is not using the function parameter for any of the steps nor the recursive call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `counter >= 1` rather than `counter > 1`.

Because for a case like `3,5,3,3` Swapping one element makes it `3,3,5,3` and it will show the array values rather than going for another recursive calls.

But,
A standard bubble sort uses nested loop. Can break the outer loop if everything is sorted(like you did with your counter variable).

Also, Swapping an element can be done much faster using good old temp variable.

```
temp = a;
a = b;
b = temp
```

OR the cool one,

```
a ^= b;
b ^= a;
a ^= b
```

Comment: Aritra, may I ask you why it is optimal for a bubble sort to use nested loop? I understand recursion is memory intensive and that it's not a good solution. Just curious as I am new to all of this.

Comment: The nested loop doesn't use call stack for every iteration. If you create a function over and over it will create all the local variables, a call stack to store them. For an approach that can be solved by recursion or iteration with same level of easiness, it is better to choose iterative because of the memory footprint.

Comment: let bubblesSort2 = (arr)=>{
 let counter = 1
 for(let i= 0; i<=arr.length; i++){
  if(counter >= 1){
   counter = 0
  } else{
   break
  }
  for(let ii = 0; ii <= arr.length; ii++){
   if(arr[ii] >= arr[ii + 1]){
    let tmp = arr[ii]
    arr[ii] = arr[ii + 1]
    arr[ii + 1] = tmp
    counter += 1
   }
  }
 }
 console.log(arr)
}